# Support of weak limit of probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mu_n$ be a sequence of probability measures on  a Polish space $E$ converging weakly to a probability measure $\mu$. What can we say in general about the support of $\mu$ in terms of the support of $\mu_n$?
Here the support $supp(\mu)$ of a probability measure is the intersection of all closed sets having measure $1$, i.e. in a Polish space the smallest closed set having measure $1$.

Comment: At least it's easy to find examples where all measures within the sequence have full support and yet the limit measure is concentrated at one atom. On the other hand diffusive measures may be approximated by discrete measures. To me this suggests one cannot say too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is kind of vague.  In some sense the answer is "nothing".  As pointed out in the comments, a sequence of absolutely continuous measures can converge to a point mass, and a sequence of purely atomic measures can converge to an absolutely continuous one.  You can also have all of the supports be disjoint from each other ($\mu_n = $ a point mass at $1/n$).